# Custom upload tool issue

Tags: html, file-upload, meteor

I am using Meteor js,HTML and CSS3 with MongoDB for an application.How can i create a custom upload tool that will access my already stored collection of files in MongoDB instead of computer directory?

Answer (score 0):

I you have files already stored in mongo, it probably means you are using gridFS. Two possibilities:

1. You use the [CollectionFS package](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) along with its [UI helpers package](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-ui)
2. You can use [file-collection package](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-file-collection), my personnal favorite. It will get you much quickly to the point, but it is less complete than CFS. However, you should have all what you need with it.